# Memory error when creating another object

Tags: c++

So I have to implement a folder and file system like linux.

My Folder objects hold one vector with Folder object and another one with Files. When ever I try to add a 2nd new item to the Folder vector within the Folder object, I'm getting a memory error. I believe I can be deleting something on accident, but I just don't know where it's possible.

> main(24984,0x7fff7d486300) malloc: *** error for object 0xe000000000000000: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   Abort trap: 6

Here is my code for the process:

```
        Folder *currentF=new Folder("Home",NULL);
        cout<<"Enter name of new directory: "<<endl;
        string tempdirName;
        cin>>tempdirName;
        Folder *folder2=new Folder(tempdirName,currentFolder);
        currentFolder->addFold(*folder2);
```

Folder.h file

```
class Folder{

private:
    string name;
    vector<File> *files;
    vector<Folder> *folders;
    Folder *upper; //the folder above this one in the tree
public:
    Folder();
    Folder(string n, Folder *u);
    string getName();
    vector<File> *getFiles();
    vector<Folder> *getFolders();
    Folder *getUpper();
    void addFold(Folder f);
    void delFold(Folder f);
    void setUpper();
    ~Folder();
};
```

folder.cpp

```
Folder::Folder(string n, Folder *u){

name=n;
upper=u;
files=new vector<File>();
folders=new vector<Folder>();

}
string Folder::getName(){
    return name;
}
vector<File> *Folder::getFiles(){
return files;
}
vector<Folder> *Folder::getFolders(){
    return folders;
}
Folder *Folder::getUpper(){
    return upper;
}
void Folder::addFold(Folder f){

    folders->push_back(f);

}
Folder::~Folder(){
    delete files;
    delete folders;
    upper=NULL;
    delete upper;
}
```

I tried making folder2=NULL after I was done with it. Did nothing. I even commented out some of the lines from ~Folder() and it still didn't work.  I still ended up with a memory leak.

Comment: In your destructor, you are modifying the upper pointer and then you are trying to delete it. Remove the `upper=NULL;` line

Comment: @Nadir, delete null is safe.

Comment: The error message says you try to `delete` something that was not `new`ed. That is not a memory leak.

Comment: Use the debugger and look at the call stack.

Comment: @user3704986 Do you have specific reasons for the overuse of raw pointers in your code? IMHO you don't need a single pointer.

Comment: I think there are serious design problems here. Why did you use vector<Folder> * and not vector<Folder *>, or vector<shared_ptr<Folder>> for example?

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @marom Or, you know, simply `vector<Folder>`. As mentioned, there's no need for any kind of pointers here.

Comment: This is a classic example of a [rule of 0/3/5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) violation. What happens if you invoke the copy constructor on a `Folder`? Both instances will try to delete the same vectors. Don't use raw pointers unless you have no choice. Here, they're purely gratuitous.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Folder::addFold(Folder f){

    folders->push_back(f);

}
```

This can't possibly work. The `push_back` function makes a copy of the specified `Folder` that is owned by the vector. But now both `f` and the newly-created `Folder` in the vector think they own the very same vectors (`*(f->files)` and `*(f->folders)`). When `f` is destroyed, its destructor deletes those vectors. When `folders` is destroyed, its destructor also deletes those very same vectors, producing the error you see.

This is why the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) exists. If you have a destructor, you probably need a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator. But really, there's no reason to be using pointers at all here. Just use vectors directly. That way, the copy of `f` placed in `folders` will get its own vector.